# Why am I getting this memory error in Python 3.8.3 64bit?

Tags: python, html, for-loop

I was tasked with writing a pyhton program to extract and clean the text from a folder containing 60 wikipedia .html files using only pyhton and its builtin functions.
The code I wrote works perfectly fine on all 58 of the files however when i try to run the code on "spanish4.html" and "french8.html" it takes like 5 minutes and then eventually gives me memory error while using all 64 gb of my RAM.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Here's the code and the html files are in "html_data", please keep in mind that this folder needs to be in the same directory as the .py code file.

code:

```
   # imports

import os

##### Libraries
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
languages = ["dutch", "english", "french", "german", "italian", "spanish"]
decode = {'à': 'a', 'á': 'a', 'ä': 'a', 'é': 'e', 'è': 'e', 'ê': 'e',
          'î': 'i', 'í': 'i', 'ô': 'o', 'ö': 'o', 'ò': 'o', 'ó': 'o',
          'ù': 'u', 'ú': 'u', 'ü': 'u', 'ç': 'c', 'ß': 'b', 'ñ': 'n'}


############################################################################
os.mkdir("text_data")
os.mkdir("cleaned_text_data")
#########################
# Html tekst extractie
def HtmlToTxt(x):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        xHtml = "html_data\\" + x + str(i) + ".html"
        fHtml = open(xHtml, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        xTxt = "text_data\\" + x + str(i) + ".txt"
        fTxt = open(xTxt, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
        write = False
        for line in fHtml:
            start = line.find("<p>")
            end = line.find("</p>")
            if start != -1:
                write = True
            if end != -1 and start == -1:
                write = False
                alleservoor = []
                for i in range(len(line) - 3):
                    alleservoor.append(line[i])
                    if line[i] == "<" and line[i + 1] == "/" and line[i + 2] == "p" and line[i + 3] == ">":
                        break
                alleservoorstring = alleservoor[0]
                for i in range(1, len(alleservoor) - 1):
                    alleservoorstring += alleservoor[i]
                if alleservoorstring != "<":
                    fTxt.write(str(alleservoorstring) + '\n')
            if write and start != -1:
                fTxt.write(line[start + 3:end] + '\n')
            if write and start == -1:
                fTxt.write(line)
            if write and start > end and end != -1:
                fTxt.write(line[start + 3:])
        fHtml.close()
        fTxt.close()
    return


# Text cleaner
def txtcleaner(x):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        filename = "text_data\\" + x + str(i) + ".txt"
        CleanedFileName = "cleaned_text_data\\" + x + str(i) + "Cleaned" + ".txt"
        fTxtDirty = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        fTxtClean = open(CleanedFileName, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
        repeat = True
        cleanNeeded = False
        for line2 in fTxtDirty:
            repeat = True
            cleanNeeded = False
            if "<" and ">" in line2:
                cleanNeeded = True
            while repeat == True and cleanNeeded == True:
                if "<" and ">" in line2:
                    start2 = line2.find("<")
                    end2 = line2.find(">")
                    line2 = line2[:start2] + line2[end2 + 1:]
                    if "<" and ">" not in line2:
                        repeat = False
            fTxtClean.write(line2)
        fTxtDirty.close()
        fTxtClean.close()
    return



for i in languages:
    HtmlToTxt(i)

for i in languages:
    txtcleaner(i)
```

here is the "html_data" folder: [html_data folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AigEK5sKcUEXg9B8w4kbVVzOEGjblg)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found the problem.
it has to do with 1) getting stuck in an infinite loop due to having more > than < or vice versa. (which I thought was not possible for html files but I guess not?)
and 2) if end2 > start2 it add the slice instead of cutting it out, creating and endless long line.

the correct code (might need some cleanup)

```
# imports

import os

##### Libraries
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
languages = ["dutch", "english", "french", "german", "italian", "spanish"]
decode = {'à': 'a', 'á': 'a', 'ä': 'a', 'é': 'e', 'è': 'e', 'ê': 'e',
          'î': 'i', 'í': 'i', 'ô': 'o', 'ö': 'o', 'ò': 'o', 'ó': 'o',
          'ù': 'u', 'ú': 'u', 'ü': 'u', 'ç': 'c', 'ß': 'b', 'ñ': 'n'}


############################################################################
os.mkdir("text_data")
os.mkdir("cleaned_text_data")
#########################
# Html tekst extractie
def HtmlToTxt(x):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        xHtml = "html_data\\" + x + str(i) + ".html"
        fHtml = open(xHtml, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        xTxt = "text_data\\" + x + str(i) + ".txt"
        fTxt = open(xTxt, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
        write = False
        for line in fHtml:
            start = line.find("<p>")
            end = line.find("</p>")
            if start != -1:
                write = True
            if end != -1 and start == -1:
                write = False
                alleservoor = []
                for i in range(len(line) - 3):
                    alleservoor.append(line[i])
                    if line[i] == "<" and line[i + 1] == "/" and line[i + 2] == "p" and line[i + 3] == ">":
                        break
                alleservoorstring = alleservoor[0]
                for i in range(1, len(alleservoor) - 1):
                    alleservoorstring += alleservoor[i]
                if alleservoorstring != "<":
                    fTxt.write(str(alleservoorstring) + '\n')
            if write and start != -1:
                fTxt.write(line[start + 3:end] + '\n')
            if write and start == -1:
                fTxt.write(line)
            if write and start > end and end != -1:
                fTxt.write(line[start + 3:])
        fHtml.close()
        fTxt.close()
    return


# Text cleaner
def txtcleaner(x):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        filename = "text_data\\" + x + str(i) + ".txt"
        CleanedFileName = "cleaned_text_data\\" + x + str(i) + "Cleaned" + ".txt"
        fTxtDirty = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        fTxtClean = open(CleanedFileName, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
        repeat = True
        cleanNeeded = False
        for line2 in fTxtDirty:
            repeat = True
            cleanNeeded = False
            if "<" in line2 and ">" in line2:
                cleanNeeded = True
            while repeat == True and cleanNeeded == True:
                if "<" in line2 and ">" in line2:
                    start2 = line2.find("<")
                    end2 = line2.find(">")
                    if start2 > end2:
                        repeat = False
                    line2 = line2[:start2] + line2[end2 + 1:]
                    if "<" not in line2 and ">" not in line2:
                        cleanNeeded = False
                elif "<" not in line2 and ">" not in line2:
                    repeat = False
                elif "<" in line2 and ">" not in line2 or "<" not in line2 and ">" in line2:
                    repeat = False
            fTxtClean.write(line2)
        fTxtDirty.close()
        fTxtClean.close()
    return



for i in languages:
    HtmlToTxt(i)

for i in languages:
    txtcleaner(i)
```